# Error on Ubuntu boot-up

Tags: boot, 22.04

I don't know why but this error keeps appearing to me, and the PC won't boot up. I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 it worked, but when restarting the PC same error appeared.

The error : `/dev/sda3/ recovering journal`
Then errors appearing to me here.

[image: Error appearing to me here]

Comment: could you post the result of `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda` ?